# MSO Review Queue Privileges are Misleading

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, privileges

When I visit Stack Overflow, I see the *review* option in the bar at the top of the screen.

[image]

However when on MSO, I don't see it. I assumed this was because I didn't have enough reputation to access the queue. I was curious what the requirement was on meta, so I moseyed on over to the privileges page. To my surprise, I saw that the privilege is listed as only requiring 500 rep and informs me I already have it:

[image]

Confused, I manually typed in meta.stackoverflow.com/review to see what would happen. The page did in fact load, but as you can see meta has no "First Posts" or "Late Answers" queue.

[image]

Seeing on that page that a minimum of 2k reputation is required to access any queues on MSO, I report the following bug:

1) On the privileges list on MSO, the 500 rep privilege of "Access first posts and late answers review queues" should not appear.

I also have the following feature request:

2) On the privileges list on MSO, it would be useful if instead there was a 2k privilege that informed you that you have access to the "Suggested Edits" and "Low Quality Posts" queues.

Comment: That might be difficult because MSO has the master copy of the privileges description, so they all need to be listed there. Technically, you do have the “access review queues” privilege, but there's nothing you can do with it since zero review queues exist on MSO at this privilege level — which is of course a highly unintuitive way of putting it.

Comment: @Gilles But the amount of rep required for privileges, as well as the order some are awarded in, is changed on beta sites. If they can be changed there, why couldn't they be changed for meta?

Comment: The privilege should be there, but it could be listed at 2k.

Comment: @Gilles That sounds great to me. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since those queues don't exist, this privilege is meaningless on Meta. We could just remove it here, but... Then it'd be really annoying to find and edit that wiki text.

So I just raised it to 2000 here (the minimum required to access the Low Quality and Suggested Edit queues, which *do* exist), turned off notifications, and tweaked the wiki a bit. This should suffice to make it less confusing.

Comment: Hey, I [asked this last week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191516/mso-review-queue-privileges-are-misleading)! ;P Thanks for the fix, it's much appreciated.

Comment: My bad; I shoulda found that.

Comment: Haha no worries. Also I just realized I forgot to +1. +1!

Comment: @WendiKidd how much rep do you need to be able upvote twice? ;)

Comment: I see the privilege still exists, but has been bumped up to 2000.  Ah well.  I guess that does the trick.  People who have 2000 rep are less likely to be confused by the reference.  Re: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192504/help-centre-refers-to-review-queues-a-privilege-and-a-link-that-do-not-exist (i.e. from someone else for whom this issue took up much time and caused much confusion), thanks!

Comment: @Shog9 I just noticed the part you added about non-existent queues.  ...even better!