# Meta SE's "access review queues" privilege mentions queues that don't exist

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, privileges, privileges-page

Having just earned 2k reputation, I received access to the first available review queues.

This is what the description on the Privileges page says:

[image: Privilege page description of 'access review queues']

> Access the First posts and Late answers review queues

However, the review queues that I actually have access to are Low quality posts and Suggested edits:

[image: The queues I actually have access to as seen in the drop-down menu of the Review queues button in the ribbon at the top of the page]

This is possibly due to the fact that for whatever reason Meta doesn't seem to have First posts and Late answers in the first place, only Low quality posts, Suggested edits, Close votes and Reopen votes:

[image: The available review queues on the Review queues page]

**I assume the privilege description is the default one and not adapted to the specifics of Meta, but do wonder if this can be changed to reflect the actual privilege gained.**

---

In reaction to *animuson*'s answer: this is the only notification I received:

[image]

Comment: *"the privilege description is the default one"* - Looks like it, and it appears to be wrong network wide too. First posts doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Nick Right, good catch!

Comment: Having this privilege [silently unlock at 2k rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192970/323179) was a decision that was made to make it less confusing from how it was. (It happened before this site became "Meta Stack Exchange", hence the references to its old name, MSO.)

Answer (score 1):

The description is not wrong. You gain access to the Suggested edits and Low quality posts queues via the [full editing privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) which just happens to be unlocked at the same reputation threshold here on Meta.

Because the two queues normally unlocked by the access to review queues privilege do not actually exist on Meta, the privilege does nothing. It was changed to 2,000 here to match the first queues you actually do unlock so people don't get the notification when they can't access anything there. It is [normally unlocked at 500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) on other sites, when you would not have access to the editing queues yet.

Comment: Okay, so technically it's not wrong, but the 'access review queues' privilege has no consequences for me as a user, and the privilege one actually receives simultaneously is not visible on the Privileges page nor communicated in another way. So my request still stands.

Comment: You should have received both privilege notifications simultaneously, since you unlocked both of them. It is [listed on the privileges page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) as well.

Comment: No, the Privileges page only mentions access to the First posts and Late answers queues. I have only received a notification that now I can edit questions and answers (see the image at the bottom of my post).

Comment: The second privilege unlocked at 2,000 reputation is called "Edit questions and answers" and is right next to it. The other queues are mentioned in that privilege, because you need to be able to edit posts in order to use them. _They are not supposed to be mentioned in the Access review queues privilege._ It is a completely different privilege. It seems as though you were only notified of the one that matters, and not notified of the review queues privilege at all... You must've just found it on your own?